# Vortordo kun subfrazo kun «ke»

Tags: word-order

Ĉu oni povas ŝanĝi la vortordon por ke parto de subfrazo estu malantaŭ rilata «ke»?

Ekzemple, ĉu estus kompreneble diri frazon kiel:

> Ĉi tiun libron mi pensas ke vi ŝatus.

Do, en tiu okazo la «ĉi tiun libron» apartenas al la subfrazo «vi ŝatus».

Ankaŭ eble oni pli nature emus fari tian frazon kun rilata vorto, ekzemple:

> Ĉi tio estas la libro kiun Johano diris ke li ŝatas.

Do, la «kiun» estas la objekto de la subfrazo «li ŝatas».

Ĉu tia vortordo estas akceptebla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambaŭ frazoj ŝajnas al mi tute bonaj. [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/vortordo/antaumetado/el_subfrazo.html) klarigas tian nekutiman vortordon de subfrazoj jene:

> **34.2.2. Antaŭmetado el subfrazo**
>
> Iafoje oni povas meti frazparton, kiu vere apartenas al subfrazo, en
>   la komencon de la tuta frazo. Tio kreas tre fortan emfazon pro la
>   malkutimeco de la vortordo:
>
> ***Tiun laboron** mi diris, ke mi faros*. = *Mi diris, ke mi faros tiun laboron*. La frazparto *tiun laboron* estas objekto de *faros*,
>   kaj apartenas plene al la *ke*-frazo. Por emfazo ĝi tamen staras
>   komence de la tuta frazo.

Via unua frazo tre similas al tiu ekzemplo de PMEG:

*ĉi tiun libron mi pensas ke vi ŝatus = mi pensas ke vi ŝatus ĉi tiun libron*

Mi kutimas meti komon antaŭ la ke-frazo (*mi pensas, ke...*).

Answer (score 4):

Viaj frazoj estas kompreneblaj, sed laŭ mia gusto ili ne apartenas al bonstila prozo. Tiaj povas ja aperi, ĉu en poezio pro metrikaj kaŭzoj, ĉu en hasta konversacio, kie foje la parolanto decidas ŝanĝi la strukturon de frazo meze de ĝi. Ekster tiaj kuntekstoj mi skribus (komo antaŭ *ke* kaj *pri kiu* estas mia prefero, sed ne ĉiuj konsentas kaj tio estas alia temo):

- *Pri ĉi tiu libro mi pensas, ke vi ŝatas ĝin.*
- *Tiu estas la libro, pri kiu Johano diris, ke li ŝatas ĝin.*

Tute akcepteblaj estas similaj demandaj frazoj, ĉar la *ki*-vortoj staras kutime en la unua loko ankaŭ se ili apartenas al subpropozicio:

- *Kion vi volas, ke mi diru?*

Tamen, *Kio vi pensas, ke estas la ĝusta respondo?* estas iom stranga pro la apudesto de senakuzativa vorto kaj transitiva verbo. En tiu kazo, mi revortumus al

- *Kio, laŭ via opinio, estas la ĝusta respondo?*

Comment: Al mi tamen ankaŭ via unua frazo sonas iomete stranga (samkiel la originala, kiun mi ja uzus verŝajne), sed mi ne scias kial; eble ĉar ‘pensi pri io’ kutime havas iom alian signifon kaj ordinare ne akceptas kroman klarigon kun *ke*. Rilate la originalan demandon… kion vi opinias pri frazoj kun demandaj korelativoj, ekzemple: *Kion vi volas, ke mi diru?*, *Kio vi pensas, ke estas la ĝusta respondo?* (La dua sonas specife stranga pro la ‘manko’ de akuzativo je ‘kio’, sed ĝi ja estas ĝusta.) Via solvo certe ne funkcias por la unua, ĉar “Pri kio vi volas, ke mi diru tion/ion” havas alian signifon.

Comment: Mi redaktis mian respondon sekve de nia koment-interŝanĝo.

Answer (score 1):

Mi opinias viajn frazojn akcepteblaj. Ili estas sufiĉe facile kompreneblaj. Pri stilo mi ne povas diri multon, sed al mi ŝajnas bone uzi tiajn frazojn, se alia vortordo estas pli malbona aŭ ne eblas. Tiaj frazoj povas soni iomete stranga, specife kiam la vorto, eltirita el la subfrazo, ne havas akuzativon:

> Kio vi pensas, ke estas la ĝusta respondo?

En tiu kazo mi ne tuj vidas pli bonan vortordon. Do verŝajne alia vortordo, se tio eblas kaj havas sencon, estas preferinda.

Mi trovis en Tekstaro, en Artikoloj el Monato, la jenan ekzemplon:

> Kaj vi ekscios, kion ili pensis, aŭdis kaj vidis, kaj ne tion, **kion ni pensas, ke ili pensis…**

(emfazo mia)

Tio estas la ununura kazo, kie tiu vortordo estas uzata en Tekstaro. Mi krome trovis ankaŭ nur uzu kazon, kie oni uzis la formon, kiun sugestis Dario, en Metropoliteno:

> Sed **pri viaj opinioj mi pensas, ke ili devenas** de via diletanteco en problemoj de l' arto.

(emfazo mia)

Comment: Ĉe via unua ekzemplo, mi elturniĝus per _Kio, laŭ via opinio, estas la ĝusta respondo?_ Vere estas iom tro strange, se la ĉefverbo estas transitiva kaj la demandovorto ne povas havi akuzativon...

Comment: Ho, tio ja estas bona elturniĝo. Mi ne pensis pri tio. Mi konsentas, ke tia frazo estas tro stranga.